# How can you give priority to a kill/rollback process under SQL server that appears to have a status 'sleeping'?

Tags: sql-server, rollback

While trying to update a table definition (change a field type from NVARCHAR(5) to NVARCHAR(8)) we caused a lock on the database. There were a large number of rows (>11,000,000) so we decided to kill the process and roll back the update.

During the rollback the status of the process was showing as 'sleeping' with a Wait Type of IO_COMPLETION or PAGEIOLATCH_EX.

How can I give the KILL/ROLLBACK process a higher priority and prevent it going to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROFL, wouldn't it be great if assigning a greater priority to a process will make your hardware faster? Both of your wait types are due to IO subsystem not keeping up. You'll just going to have to wait it out.

Comment: OK, thought it was probably going to be something like that. I think we had something else going on with the server at the time which was causing it to slow down generally. Sorry for the silly question and thanks for explaining the wait types were due to hardware.